# type hint: how should type of lru_cache be defined?

Tags: python, mypy

Given the following function

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def get_response_from_api() -> List[ApiObject]:
    url = _get_api_url()
    response = requests.get(url).text
    return json.loads(response, object_hook=_create_api_obj)
```

when running

> mypy predictor --ignore-missing-imports --strict

I am getting the error message:

> error: Untyped decorator makes function "get_response_from_api" untyped

How can i fix this ?

How should i annotate the lru_cache function?

Comment: @NPE - i don't get how this link answers my question. I already annotated my function but the lru_cache could somehow change the return value. Which type annotation should i put in the lru_cache line to tell that i return List[ApiObject]?

Comment: It looks like Mypy includes an annotation for `lru_cache` [1](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/8b84e9cf13ee20afd801e3d03b7a6700fea69222/stdlib/3/functools.pyi#L23) but it does not work for me either.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a bug in mypy: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5107

According to [Ethan Smith](https://github.com/ethanhs) (which is a core developer of mypy): as the `get_response_from_api` function takes no arguments, the type is inferred as `lru_cache[Any]`. This should be fixed